# Using background-clip on a gradient overlay

Tags: html, css, gradient, background-clip

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
[image]

Both elements (the arrow container + full width bar) share the same gradient. What I've tried is to make both elements separately and just apply the gradient to both of them, but for obvious reasons it looks clipped:

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/bGarpvJ

**Snippet:**

```css
.container {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 71px;
}

.arrow-container {
  height: 34px;
  width: 118px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #415fb4 0%, #0e2460 100%) 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
}

.bar {
  height: 37px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #415fb4 0%, #0e2460 100%) 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-container">&#x2191;</div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

I then got the idea of using a full width + full height overlay with the gradient, and then using `background-clip` to clip the two elements, so they both share the gradient. But I'm struggling a bit with it, and it seems like I'm using it the wrong way around.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/popryWz

**Snippet:**

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 71px;
}

.bg-gradient {
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #415fb4 0%, #0e2460 100%) 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.arrow-container {
  height: 34px;
  width: 118px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.bar {
  height: 37px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-gradient">
      <div class="arrow-container">&#x2191;</div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot use `::after` & `::before` pseudo-elements, they need to be two separate elements as the arrow-element needs an eventhandler.
Am I on the right path, or is this even achievable?

Thank you!

Comment: No need to apply clip-path, Just put gradient in both div. In full width div use #0A225A to #17367A, then in arrow one div use #17367A to #2C52A8

Comment: It will give u visualization like, that is in single div with full height gradient.

Comment: It didn't produce what I wanted 100%, but decent solution nonetheless. Thanks for the suggestion. @VIKESIR

Comment: You can see @temani solution, That's what i am talking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the height of the gradient equal to the sum of both element then control the size:

```css
.container {
  background: white;
  height: 71px;
}

.arrow-container {
  height: 34px;
  width: 118px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(180deg, #415fb4 0%, #0e2460 100%) top/100% 71px;
}

.bar {
  height: 37px;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(180deg, #415fb4 0%, #0e2460 100%) bottom/100% 71px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-container">&#x2191;</div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Or do it like below using pseudo element:

```css
.container {
  background: white;
  height: 71px;
  position:relative; /* relative here */
  z-index: 0;
}

.arrow-container {
  height: 34px;
  width: 118px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}

.bar {
  height: 37px;
}

.arrow-container,
.bar {
 -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#000 0 0); /* clip the gradient to the element area */
}

/* your gradient here */
.arrow-container:before,
.bar:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #415fb4 0%, #0e2460 100%);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-container">&#x2191;</div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```